# Can 2 equations defining the same curve be put together?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have the following relation

$$X -1\quad 0 \quad 2 \quad 3$$
$$Y -8 \quad 3 \quad 1 \quad 12$$

I can define the relation as

$\begin{array}{rcrl}
11X-Y&=&-3&\text{ for $X$ between $-1$ and $0$}\\
  X+Y&=& 3&\text{ for $X$ between  $0$ and $2$}\\
11X-Y&=&21&\text{ for $X$ between  $2$ and $3$}\end{array}$

Obtained these equations by $2$ point method $[[(y_2-y_1)/(y_1-y)]-[(x_2-x_1)/(x_1-x)]]$

Can these equations be put together into 1 equation which satisfies all the above values?

Any other methods to do the same will be helpful

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Comment: No, your function is piecewise linear, so you can only define it using three different rules.

Comment: ...unless you want to use step functions...

Comment: I have come across Lagrange's interpolation method just wondering if there is any other simpler way